# Problem in python animation and saving animation

Tags: python, animation

I am trying to simulate the dynamics of a system under the action of some parameters. However, the animation doesn't seem to work out, inspite of everything I've tried. Can you please help me out? Thank you in advance.

Here, C is a (2N) dimensional vector, dependent upon time and 2 other parameters. I'm trying to simulate the dynamics of C for every instant of time for every set of values of the 2 parameters.

```
def scatterupdate(i,fig,scat,N,C,j,k):
    z=np.zeros(shape=(2*N,2))
    for m in range(2*N):
        z[m][0]=m+1
        z[m][1]=abs(C[i][j][k][m])**2
    m=np.arange(1,2*N+1,1)
    scat.set_offsets(z)
    return scat,

for i in range(np.size(v0,axis=0)):
    for j in range(np.size(omega,axis=0)):
        fig2=plt.figure(figsize=(10,5))
        scat=plt.scatter(np.arange(1,2*N+1,1),abs(C[0][i][j])**2)
        anim=animation.FuncAnimation(fig2,scatterupdate,fargs=(fig2,scat,N,C,i,j),frames=np.size(t,axis=0),interval=200,blit=False,repeat=True)
        plt.show()anim.save(r'$v_0=%f,\omega=%f$.gif'%v0[i],omega[j]),writer='imagemagick',fps=30)
```

The last line isn't on the same line as plt.show(). I'm sorry for the misunderstanding.

I'm getting an empty graph. I couldn't get rid of this problem

Comment: Do you have ImageMagick installed? You are trying to use it within you plt.show as the writer.

Comment: I think I do. In any case, I tried with ffmpeg also. It wasn't of any use